# How to export with state abbreviations

Tags: export

We are using Civi 4.7.27 on Wordpress 4.9
When doing exports the state is shown as the full name. We really need to be able to export with the 2 letter state abbreviation.  How can we set it to do this?

Thank you.

*****Added Screenshot***

[image]

Comment: The default is to export the state abbreviation.  In fact, I'm not sure how I'd go about doing the opposite.  Can you try replicating your steps on the demo server to see if it's something specific to your site?  I just tried it and got the abbreviations.

Comment: That is interesting.  In Civi  Dashboard I am going to  Reports > Contribution Reports > Contribution Details > I check City, state, zip code > Select "Export to CSV" and the Export shows the State names typed out in full not the 2 letter abbreviation as you can see from the screen shot I added.   What am I doing wrong?  Is there another export method I should use?

Comment: I'm not sure about this but the result you are getting is maybe because of your setting in administer> localization> address settings> address display.
In the 5th line in display format, it may show contact.state_province_name} instead of {contact.state_province}.  The latter displays only a state abbreviation.
The help caption below says "Format for displaying addresses in the Contact Summary and Event Information screens.
Use {contact.state_province} for state/province abbreviation or {contact.state_province_name} for state province name."
Might be worth a try changing the setting!

Comment: I just it does say contact.state_providence like it is supposed to.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It seems the problem is that you're using CiviReport rather than Advanced Search to perform your export.  If you use search and the Export search action, you'll get abbreviated state names.

Since you're exporting contributions, don't forget to set *Display Results As* to **Contributions**.  See screenshot:
[image]

Comment: That helped. Now I can export with the state abbreviation by doing what you suggested.  However it does not include the contribution amount anymore and that doesn't seem to be an available field in the Select Field options.

Comment: Great, almost there! This last issue is because Advanced Search displays contacts, not contributions, by default.  I updated my answer to show how to display results as contributions - then you can export amounts too!

Comment: Thank you.  Now I am getting all the information I need in the format I need it in with those updated instructions.