# Can I make reports export the state/province abbreviation instead of full name?

Tags: civireport, custom-reports

Similar to [this question](https://civicrm.stackexchange.com/questions/21743/how-to-export-with-state-abbreviations), I'm interested in having my reports export states/provinces with the abbreviation instead of the full name. The accepted answer in that case was to use an Advanced Search rather than a Report -- but [in my case there is no advanced search to get the contacts I need](https://civicrm.stackexchange.com/questions/22717/searching-filtering-by-the-date-a-contact-was-added-to-a-group) and I'm using a custom report, so I need to figure out how to do this in the CiviReport side.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Take a look at the "Contributions by Organization Report".  `CRM/Report/Form/Contribute/OrganizationSummary.php` and the line:

```
$rows[$rowNum]['civicrm_address_state_province_id'] = CRM_Core_PseudoConstant::stateProvinceAbbreviation($value, FALSE);
```

Comment: Thanks – this core report helped me tweak the custom report I have been using enough to get what I need. I appreciate the pointer.